# Наследование свойства IsEnabled в TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите как решить следующую проблему. Есть TabControl с несколькими TabItem. Каждый TabItem в начальный момент недоступен (IsEnabled = false), рядом с TabControl присутствуют CheckBox-ы, после нажатия на которые активируется соответствующие TabItem. Как активировать и деактивировать это понятно - присваиваю каждому TabItem уникальное имя и у CheckBox прописываю реакцию на check/uncheck. Начал заполнять TabItem-ы элементами типа TextBox и др. - после компиляции выяснилось, что несмотря на то что они помещались в Grid принадлежащий неактивному TabItem, но сами по неизвестной причине активны и не унаследовали IsEnabled=false. Как можно просто решить эту проблему? В принципе понятное дело, каждому элементу можно прописать имя и в check/uncheck включать/выключать, но может есть способ заставить унаследовать IsEnabled TabItem-а?

Comment: По идее достаточно сделать неактивной только панель и все что на ней лежит отключится. Т.е. `(myTabItem.Content as Control).IsEnabled = myTabItem.IsEnabled`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В дизайнере студии щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по `TabControl` и выберите <kbd>Edit Template</kbd>><kbd>Edit a Copy...</kbd> и добавьте шаблон элемента к себе в проект.

В шаблоне вы увидите такую структуру:

```
<Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ...>
    <TabPanel x:Name="headerPanel" ... />
    <Border x:Name="contentPanel" ...>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" ... />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Как видно, заголовки `TabItem`'ов и их контент лежат рядом и не вложены друг в друга, это объясняет почему свойства `TabItem` не наследуются его контентом. Это можно исправить прямо в шаблоне, добавьте такую привязку:

```
    <Border x:Name="contentPanel" ...
            IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}, Path=SelectedItem.IsEnabled}">
```

Comment: Замечательно, работает, спасибо)))