# C# WPF не могу забиндить DelegateCommand к User Control который внутри TabItem Template

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть Tab Item Template внутри которого мой User Control который имеет свойство Command (binding к Button). Мне нужно задать ему Command из View Model и я пытаюсь сделать ето через Extension. По отдельности мой User Control работает и если в template заменить его на просто Button то работает Extension. Но бинд с Extension к его свойству Command выдает ошибку.

View Model (Tab)

```
protected DelegateCommand _hideCommand;
public DelegateCommand HideCommand {
  get => this._hideCommand;
  set => SetProperty(ref this._hideCommand, value);
}
```

Tab Control (биндиться к ObservableCollection Tab'ов) Tabs

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource TabItemControlTemplae}"/>
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
            <Setter Property="m:Extensions.HideCommand" Value="{Binding HideCommand}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>
</TabControl>
```

внутри TabItemControlTemplate мой User Control

```
<ucb:CancelButton Command="{Binding (m:Extensions.HideCommand), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Собственно Error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: '(m:Extensions.HideCommand)' property not found on 'object' ''TabItem' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(m:Extensions.HideCommand); DataItem='TabItem' (Name=''); target element is 'CancelButton' (Name='self'); target property is 'Command' (type 'DelegateCommand')
```

Extension:

```
public class Extensions {
public static readonly DependencyProperty HideCommandProperty =
 DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HideCommand", typeof(DelegateCommand),
  typeof(Extensions), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
public static DelegateCommand GetHideCommand(DependencyObject obj)
    => (DelegateCommand)obj.GetValue(HideCommandProperty);

public static void SetHideCommand(DependencyObject obj, DelegateCommand value)
    => obj.SetValue(HideCommandProperty, value);
}
```

и внутри User Control:

```
public DelegateCommand Command
{
  get => (DelegateCommand)GetValue(CommandProperty);
  set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Command", typeof(DelegateCommand), typeof(CancelButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

User Control XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding ElementName=self, Path=Command}"/>
```

Comment: Почему стиль применяете не через `ItemContainerStyle`?

Comment: Визуальное дерево изучите в рантайме, точно ли кнопка лежит внутри TabItem? Потому что вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880724/218063

Comment: @Андрей NOP, я убираю user control из template и ставлю на его место просто Button с тем же биндингом для Command и обычный Button работает

Comment: А ошибка в дизайнтайме или в рантайме тоже есть?

Comment: в рантайме, когда открывается shell window и подгружается регион в котором Tab Control

Comment: получаеться extension работает если там внутри обычный button и не работает с моим user control, а мой user control работает сам по себе если его вынести из Template и забиндить к Tabs[0].HideCommand к примеру, а биндинг одного к другому выдает ошибку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85786/discussion-between-mike-waters-and--nop).