# TabControls и MVVM: Многоуровневое связывания DataContext и ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, tabcontrol

День добрый.

Проблема следующая: есть **TabContol**, где

*Workspaces is ObservableCollection* (из **XAML WinMainViewModel**)

```
<TabControl Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}">
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type workspace:PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel}">
            <vw:PropertyWorkspace />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type workspace:PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderText}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Коллекция **Workspaces** определяется, когда меняется выделенный элемент **TreeView**

```
public NodeViewModel SelectedNode {
    get => _SelectedNode;
    set {
        this.SetProperty(ref _SelectedNode, value);
        Workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> {
            new PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel(value)
        };
    }
}
```

В зависимости от того, какой **value** (т.е. производный класс от *NodeViewModel*) придёт в мутатор **SelectedNode.set**
определится количество и тип моделей производных от *WorkspaceViewModel*

Я выбираю - всё работает, значение в HeaderText сливается

```
    internal sealed class PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel : WorkspaceViewModel
    {
        public PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel(NodeViewModel node)
        {
            HeaderText = "Свойства " + node.Disp;

            //PropertyControls = new List<SectionViewModel> {
            //    new NodeSectionViewModel(node)
            //};
        }

        public PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel() { }

        public List<SectionViewModel> PropertyControls { get; }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ПРОБЛЕМА 1:** переключаюсь с узлов **TreeView** и (через раз!) **TabItem** выделяется (активный, как будто по вкладке нажал пользователь) И через раз падает ошибка >>

1. Серьезность: Ошибка
2. Число: 12 (когда она возникает, то +4 сразу)
3. Контекст данных: null
4. Путь привязки: TabStripPlacement
5. Целевой объект: TabItem.NoTarget
6. Конечный тип: Object
7. Описание: Не удается найти источник: RelativeSource FindAncestor,
   AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl',
   AncestorLevel='1'.

**ПРОБЛЕМА 2:** не могу по такой же логике внутрь Шаблона Контента TabItem Привязать реализацию секций

*ViewModel* **Workspace** имеет **ЕЩЁ** коллекцию *ViewModel* секций

```
ObservableCollection<SectionViewModel> PropertyControls
```

Тут он видит и связывает, а при запуске ПУСТО. Руки опускаются...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**XAML WorkspaceView**

```
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <w:PropertyWorkspaceViewNodel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PropertyControls}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:NodeSectionViewModel}">
                <sv:NodeSection />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**XAML SectionViewModel**

```
   <UserControl.DataContext>
        <s:NodeSectionViewModel />
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    
    <StackPanel Background="White">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Padding="10" FontSize="14pt" Foreground="White" Background="Black" />
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Системное имя" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Disp}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
            <TextBlock Text="Имя" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Disp}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Прошу помощи! Заранее спасибо!
Оставлю тут ссылки:
Discord: ! Красный Рыцарь#9927
Telegram: @PHXHKR

Comment: Из того, что видно невооруженным взглядом: `<UserControl.DataContext>` - вы так сбиваете `DataContext` объекта, дайте свободу, пусть сам его установит, да и вообще, `DataContext` в View слое это плохо и нарушение MVVM. Далее, всякие `public List<SectionViewModel> PropertyControls { get; }` - где INPC? У вас пустое, неинициализированное свойство, которому вы скорей всего потом делаете `= new...`, что в свою очередь порождает другое свойство и UI про него не знает. Ну и на последок, как по мне, такие проблемы надо сопровождать минимальным, самодостаточном примером, чтобы люди могли запустить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ PropertyControls тип изменил на ObservableCollection<>, свойство инициализируется в конструкторе WorkspaceViewModel

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Можно Вас попросить пояснений почему <UserControl.DataContext> == плохо? Как я понял второй вариант это в Code-Behind сносить, но у меня ни строчки CB нет, так красиво идёт. Прошу пояснить

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553

Comment: А где у вас привязка с FindAncestor, не вижу в тексте вопроса. Вообще, на сколько я помню, с TabContol есть нюансы, контент создаётся только для активной вкладки, поэтому привязка не срабатывает на момент ее создания https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/880724/218063, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/943427/218063

Comment: Какую задачу вы решаете? Что делает приложение? Как это запустить, потестировать?